# Menustrip like Combobox

Tags: c#, combobox, menustrip

Is there any GUI tool that resembles a dropdown list like the combobox one, but would allow me to add choices in the design phase, and configure the events for each choice like in a menustrip?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can use the designer to make a context menu, then draw a normal button on your form.  When they click the button align the context menu with the bottom/left of the button and tell the context menu to open.

Comment: I guess thats the route I'm taking :)